# How do I map between the Cocoa object documentation and the Objective-C calling conventions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on a MacOS application in Rust. Rust doesn't currently have any good libraries for binding to Cocoa (it does have a complete one, but one that eliminates all of the benefits of static type checking), so I'm trying to use Objective-C to generate the objects myself.

However, how can I understand the Cocoa documentation well enough to know what the method names are?

For example: [NSWindow init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419477-init)

```
NSWindow init(contentRect: NSRect,
              styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask,
              backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType,
              defer: Bool)
```

This corresponds to (using `objc` crate from Rust):

```
msg_send![self.ptr,
          initWithContentRect:rect
          styleMask:style.bits
          backing:backing as NSUInteger
          defer:defer_]
```

And [NSWindow cascadeTopLeft](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419392-cascadetopleft)

```
NSWindow func cascadeTopLeft(from: NSPoint) -> NSPoint
```

corresponds to

```
msg_send![self.ptr, cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:point]
```

I've figured this two out by doing some googling and reading other people's code. But what is the pattern? How do I go about figuring out the correct message to send from Apple's documentation?

Comment: You are looking at the Swift documentation, not the Objective-C documentation.

Comment: What rmaddy said. There's a language pop-up in the black bar across the top of the page. You can switch between Swift and Objective-C there. Your choice is remembered so future links will be redirected to your chosen language (if the link itself doesn't specify a language).

Comment: ... :facepalm: ... thank you. I never even considered that I may have run across the wrong language documentation.